# Android LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()

Tags: android

From android documentation LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation():

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider.
>
> ```
> Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.
> ```

How often provider updates device location ? How its works ?

The reason why I asking is that I dont want to use locationListener,
I just need to get current geo location on button click, and thats it.
Can I just do like this ?

```
    final LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final Location currentGeoLocation = mlocManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How often provider updates device location ? How its works ?

It depends, and you may never know. If a device has good reception then updates about the user's location will fire rapidly.

> Can I just do like this ?

Not really. If that is firing too soon then you will not get any location back. If the user doesn't have great reception then it could take 10 seconds before you have a reasonable idea of the user's location. I think you'll have to approach this slightly differently. I'm afraid I must recommend locationListeners :P

Answer (score 1):

if you absolutely can't wait for a location you can try `getLastKnownLocation()`, but you need to be prepared to have a `NULL` result.

`getLastKnownLocation()` is just a cache of the last location from the provider you specified.  In some cases there won't be one at all, like when the phone just rebooted.  Even when there is a cached location it may not be accurate.